# Need images of Codex Alexandrinus & Leningrad

Tags: genesis, tools-of-biblical-studies

Where can I find the actual photographed images of Genesis in both the Codex Alexandrinus and Leningradensis? Hoping to get these with English translations but if that doesn't exist, any suggestions on how to identify a verse are appreciated. I'm looking for Genesis 2:7 photographed in both these codexes. Found a couple links but the images are distorted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are both available online. Leningradensis can be viewed from [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/Leningrad_Codex). Here is [Genesis 2:7](https://archive.org/stream/Leningrad_Codex/Leningrad#page/n8/mode/2up) (from the second column of the right-hand page):

[image]

Many of the digitised Greek codices are available from the [Center for the Study of New Testament Manuscripts](http://www.csntm.org). The [images of Alexandrinus](http://www.csntm.org/Manuscript/View/GA_02) there are apparently not the newest, but they are adequate. Here is Gen 2:7:

[image]

From what I have found, the British Library (where Alexandrinus is housed) has only made available on their website images of the New Testament from that Codex.

The only way I'm aware to identify verses in either of these resources is to estimate the location among the ordered pages and then read the text.

Comment: Thank you, Susan! The photos and the links are much appreciated.